# nativescript: How to view backstack?

Tags: nativescript

I have an app that on android crashes when hit the back button.  I want to ensure there are a stack of views to go back to.  How can I log the backstack in order to see the views that are added to the stack?

Comment: How do you handle your routing? Are you using Nativescript Angular or Vue?

Comment: @Joest using Vue

Comment: How do you handle routing? Can you share some code?